# how to fix error "DataFrame object is not callable" in python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, onchange, streamlit

I have a python code that display **dataframe** and allow the user to filter the dataframe by creating a **new dataframe** and allow him to update the requested record using  the index number from the selectedbox.

For this reason i am using the new feature of streamlit **session state** where i want the system to preserve the filtered dataframe  after the **user change the the value of the selectbox** by using the **callback feature**

The problem is that once the user select the value from the selectbox the system crash and display the below error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
Traceback:
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 347, in _run_script
    self._session_state.call_callbacks()
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\state\session_state.py", line 379, in call_callbacks
    self._new_widget_state.call_callback(wid)
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\state\session_state.py", line 203, in call_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
        
def update_df(new_df):
    return pd.DataFrame(new_df)
        
def main():
    df=pd.read_csv(data)
    df_result_search = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df, columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description])
    df_len = range(len(df_result_search.index))
    s = st.selectbox('Select index',key="select_box",options=df_len,on_change=update_df(df_result_search))
    expander_updates_fields = st.beta_expander('Update Records')
    with expander_updates_fields:
            for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
                  if not s == 0:
                     val_update = st_input_update('Update {} from {} to:'.format(col, df[col].values[s]))
                     expander_updates_fields.markdown(val_update, unsafe_allow_html=True)
                  else:
                      st.write("DataFrame is empty")
    
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

based on the answer of **Joran Beasley**

the system return the selected value but is not showing the dataframe

after the user select the value the page refresh this what is happening:

1. dataframe disapper
2. selectbox is saved the selected value
3. the update expander return all the values of all records in each
   column.

So for this reason i used the **callback()**

what i want is to :

1. dataframe still appear.
2. selectbox is saved the selected value
3. the update expander return values of the selected index number in
   each
   column.

**How can I achieve these 3 tasks???**

[image]

Comment: I followed up with another example ./.. Im guessing you dont actually care about `on_change` at all and you are expecting it to work like onchange in javascript or something  ... just use s after you make the select (it recalls the whole thing anytime you change it)

Comment: i edit my question and add the **expander update** and what happen and what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry I dont quite understand what you are trying to do... :/

Comment: @ Joran Beasley what i am trying to do is to allow the user to first search in the dataframe based on text_input. 
then i am trying to allow the user to update the values of the  selected record (from the selectbox) by displaying the current values of columns related to that record in the **expander update**  Is there a better way to do this task ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing

`on_change=lambda: update_df(df_result_search)`

before you basically had

```
a_df = update_df(df_result_search)
... on_change=a_df
```

on_change needs a function that it can call ... it cannot call the dataframe returned ... in the suggested solution we simply convert it into a lambda that will be called when the select choice is changed.

(of coarse it probably passes some sort of "change_event" that you should probably use to select a column or something)

`...on_change= lambda evt:do_something_with_event(evt)`

on further examination I think you do not quite understand how streamlit works

this example should help you understand why you still have some issues

```
import streamlit as st


def main():
    s = st.selectbox('Select index',key="select_box",options=['a','b','c'],on_change=lambda *a:print("Old selection:",s))
    print("Current selection:",s) # now do something with it

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i will edit my question and add the result that it display after i tried your answer .